# What is the idMso for teams meeting in an Outlook Meeting Ribbon?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, microsoft-teams

Does anyone know the idMso for teams meeting (Microsoft Teams Add In) in an Outlook Meeting Ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you want to make a meeting that is a Teams Meeting. Microsoft obviously doesn’t want vsto addins anymore as is evident from Microsoft Teams.

You can however [create a deep link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) For the meeting which will present the user with the meeting in teams but should be then saved back into a calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This is an add-in in Outlook. Microsoft doesn't expose their IDs.